# Flutter carousel_slider 4.0.0 error type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List<int>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, carousel-slider

I'm using my flutter (null safety version) app for **[carousel_slider 4.0.0](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider/example)** , slider worked but, I faced this error

> type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'List' in type cast

any solution for this?

[image]
my code here

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:rmapp/provider/theme_provider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  //swiper current index

  late final List<String> imageList = [
    "https://www.setaswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/08/Spiderman-Wallpaper-76-1280x720.jpg",
    "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/yL2FmQfZA79S5eIDza9MH2NjKGIKWPOGRHxHdYwiNPcYDW26YmK6qnP01ZDLsBENZpiADc1ohkj3LzVjrwoX8Pb-crT6MYZb3Jp9gy3ZrlET_yvoFS0qtUHLq4DtVPcqIdxPiNWI_j08omBVACv-YJc",

  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context).themeMode == ThemeMode.dark
        ? 'DarkTheme'
        : 'LightTheme';
    return Scaffold(
      // Setting up AppBar
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,

       

      ),

      // Setting up Background Color


      // Body
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
          children: <Widget>[

            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, bottom: 10, top: 10,),
              child: Text(
                'Hi, Welcome back!',
                //style: mTitleStyle,
              ),
            ),
            //Promo Slider
            _promoSlider(),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }


  //Promo Slider
  Widget _promoSlider() {
    return Container(



            child: CarouselSlider(
              options: CarouselOptions(
                enlargeCenterPage: true,
                enableInfiniteScroll: false,
                autoPlay: true,
              ),
              items: imageList.map((e) => ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                child: Stack(
                  fit: StackFit.expand,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Image.network(e,
                      width: 1050,
                      height: 350,
                      fit: BoxFit.cover,)
                  ],
                ) ,
              )).toList(),
                ),);

  }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you could try adding null checks against list that causes the error

Comment: @Cyrill I'm not clear, can you please add the solution

Comment: Could you try replacing items: with a concrete widgete list? Like  var list = <Widget>[];

    for (var i = 0; i < imageList; i++) {
    list.add(Image.networkt(...)
 }

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad not working

Comment: I would assume that something in your imageList is null. Can you confirm its not?

Comment: @LOLWTFasdasdasdad Thanks Got it, yeah something mistake

Comment: Just for the sake of completness I'll file an answer in case anyone else stumbles across a similiar error / situation. Feel free to acceppt it when the bounty has expired since I didn't really do anything I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could indicate that something in your `imageList` is null.
The `CarouselSlider` requires non null parameters for key / value purposes in its `items` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

your second link:
https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/proxy/yL2FmQfZA79S5eIDza9MH2NjKGIKWPOGRHxHdYwiNPcYDW26YmK6qnP01ZDLsBENZpiADc1ohkj3LzVjrwoX8Pb-crT6MYZb3Jp9gy3ZrlET_yvoFS0qtUHLq4DtVPcqIdxPiNWI_j08omBVACv-YJc

returns a 404, not a image.

get another one

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue.  While deleting the bad link solves the problem, it doesn't prevent the issue from reoccuring without manual intervention.
So I ended up writing a short piece of code that essentially cleans up the imageList prior to passing it to Carousel Slider.  Here's the relevent snippet:

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<bool> photoExists(String photourl) async {
        final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(photourl));
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }

List imageList = original_imageList;  // replace original_imageList with the appropriate list of urls
    for (String singleImage in imageList) {
      photoExists(singleImage).then((value) {
        if (!value) {
          imageList.remove(singleImage);
        }
      });
    }
```

now you can use the imageList in the items: property of Carousel Slider

Note: as this is a future, you may get the null error message in the console but you will not see the "null" image in the Carousel Slider